# Why recursion solution not working here?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, recursion

> Raashan, Sylvia, and Ted play the following game. Each starts with $\$1$. A bell rings every $15$ seconds, at which time each of the players who currently have money simultaneously chooses one of the other two players independently and at random and gives $\$1$ to that player. What is the probability that after the bell has rung $2019$ times, each player will have $\$1$? (For example, Raashan and Ted may each decide to give $\$1$ to Sylvia, and Sylvia may decide to give her dollar to Ted, at which point Raashan will have $\$0$, Sylvia will have $\$2$, and Ted will have $\$1$, and that is the end of the first round of play. In the second round Rashaan has no money to give, but Sylvia and Ted might choose each other to give their $\$1$ to, and the holdings will be the same at the end of the second round.)

> Source: [AMC $2019$B Problem $22$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2019_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_22)

I am trying to solve the problem by recursion. Other solutions are already presented on the link above. However, I can't spot the error in my solution.

---

Let $a_n$ be the probability that after the bell has rung $n$ times, everyone will have one dollar each.

Let $b_n$ be the probability that after the bell has rung $n$ times, Raashan, Sylvia, and Ted will get $2,1,0$ respectively.

First we try to find $a_{n+1}$

- From $(1,1,1)$ there are $2^3=8$ possible ways to distribute it. It's easy to see that there are exactly two ways to get to $(1,1,1)$ again.
- From $(2,1,0)$ there are $4$ ways to distribute it. Only $1$ way to get $(1,1,1)$. Taking permutations into account, there are $3!=6$ ways.

So we have $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{4}+\frac{6b_n}{4}=\frac{a_n}{4}+\frac{3b_n}{2}$$
Next we try to find $b_{n+1}$.

- There are $2^3=8$ ways to distribute $(1,1,1)$. Only one results in $(2,1,0)$.
- There are $4$ ways to distribute $(2,1,0)$. Only one results in $(2,1,0)$

So we have $$b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{8}+\frac{b_n}{4}$$

Solving with the initial conditions of $a_0=1,b_0=0$ (There's no need to solve it given that options are simple suggests that there is most likely a pattern here). We get that
$$a_n=2^{-2n-1}((1-\sqrt{3})^n + (1+\sqrt{3})^n)).$$
But $a_{2019}$ is not in the option.

Comment: Have you double checked that $a_n + b_n = 1$ always holds with your solution? That would be my first instinct to try to catch a mistake.

Comment: @Arthur $a_n+b_n=1$ shouldn't apply since $b_n$ only counts in a specific order by definition.

Comment: Then $a_n + 6b_n = 1$. My point still stands. (Also, I think it would be easier to work with $b_n$ being the probability of having any of the six $(2, 1, 0)$ type money distributions rather than a particular one. But it should work either way.)

Comment: @Arthur I think it's false. But I am unable to spot the error.

Comment: Maybe try to change the definition of $b_n$ to what I described? If nothing else then just to make a change of perspective, forcing yourself to a fresh start.

Comment: I agree with Arthur.  there are only two relevant states: the money is evenly distributed or it isn't.  In either case, the probability of going to the evenly-distributed state is $\frac14$ and the probability of going to the unevenly distributed state is $\frac34$.

Comment: $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$ in your definition could also result from a previous state which was neither $a_{n}$ nor $b_{n}$. Hence your recursive equations don't stand. You should redefine $b_n$ as $(2,1,0)$ in any order.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I redefined $b_n$ and got the answer. But I still don't see why the above solution isn't true. Which previous state have I not counted?

Comment: The new $b_n$ is six times the value of the old $b_n$. Look through your workings in both cases, compare the two, and see where in the recursive formulas this 6-to-1 ratio is not respected. That's where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $a_{n+1}$ is correct. The $b_{n+1}$ isn't. $(2,1,0)$ can be reached from $(1,1,1),(2,1,0),(0,2,1), (2,0,1)$. So it should be
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{8} + \frac{3b_n}{4}$$
since there three out of four ($(2,1,0),(0,2,1), (2,0,1)$) are valid.